# edit attribute value in bash shell unix script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Guys i have an xml where they have `requestID`attrbute and i want to change its value - it can be in lof of forms like this:

```
<ns0:requestID>12345</ns0:requestID>
<requestID>12345</requestID>
<requestID>12345667</requestID><anyOtherAttribute>131241</anyOtherAttribute>
```

any suggestion how to make it through "sed" ? - Thanks

Comment: So do you want to change both `12345` and `12345667` to another value?  Different values for each `requestID`, or just the first 5 digits?

Answer (score 1):

> any suggestion how to make it through "sed" ?

This simple substitution command handles the shown cases:

```
sed 's,\<requestID>[^<]*,requestID>CHANGE,'
```

> can you tell me what does it means ?

- `s,regexp,replacement,` - Attempt to match `regexp` against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that portion matched with `replacement`.
- `\<` - match the empty string at the beginning of a word
- `[^<]` - matches any character but `<`
- `*` - The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
- `CHANGE` - value to which you *want to change*

Comment: can you tell me what does it means ?

Comment: I added explanations.